# React native app stuck on splash screen on device but works in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

My React Native app works in the XCode simulator with no issues, but when I run in a physical device, my iPhone, there's a problem. The app launches and gets stuck on the React Native splash screen, the after 10-15 seconds the app crashes/closes. What's the cause of this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I have a similar one. My app does work on both simulator and devices of iphone 5S and up. However after login app closes itself on iphone 5 and 4S.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue, my app works completely fine in iOS simulator but does not work on my device after first load.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It seems that I have found the problem. According to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device, when you build and run the app on your device, your app will load js files from the packager on your computer, so you can live reload your app. That means your device has to be connected to your computer or has to be in the same wifi network as your computer. If your device can't access the packager, it will stuck on the splash screen and quit.

To run on your device reliably, edit build schema and build release version.

Comment: We were seeing the same thing, app would time out (or display "no bundle URL present" after quite a while) when phone not on wifi.  Fixed by Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, and switching the Run step to Release.

Comment: This was it for me, too. Thanks.

Comment: I am on same network but no luck even after switching to release mode.

Comment: Switching both mobile and computer to the same WI-FI network worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Still didn't work (the first time) after switching to Release mode--said my iPhone wasn't connected. Had to unplug and plug the phone back in & just keep trying the Release build until it worked.

Comment: The lack of any hint to the user is discombobulating

Answer (score 19):

For me when I build, it was working fine in simulator however, in actual device only splash screen was coming and nothing else.

This was because my build configuration was debug mode which is default I guess, I had to change release/build configuration from debug to release and everything work as expected.

[image]

Comment: This disables the debug/developer menu.

Comment: Dear @Anjum. In the Archive section, I am using **Debug** instead of **Release**. I want to create an archive and push it to TestFlight. I am getting the this Issue. Should I use the Release?

Answer (score 9):

Yep I had WiFi on my phone disabled. Enabled WiFi and boom back in business

Comment: Save me from my struggles. Trick is to have both the phone and mac book connected to same wifi. Boom its starts working.

Answer (score 6):

It should be perfectly possible to run the app in debug, on the device, without the packager attached!  You have to use `react-native bundle` to create an offline bundle, and add it to your Xcode project.  Then your app should fall back to that bundle when the packager is not available.

This used to be in the Deploying to Device FB docs, not sure why it's not there anymore.

Sample call (our `index.ios.js` is placed in `./dist` by TypeScript):

```
react-native bundle --dev true --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file ./dist/index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

Also, it's apparently necessary to tell your app to run directly from the bundle rather than try to access the development server, which seems to cause the timeout (we had the same issue as OP).

Comment out this line:

```
jsCodeLocation = // whatever
```

And add this line:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Comment: I always create the bundle, but not changing the jsCodeLocation. I am not getting any timeout but still get this issue

Answer (score 3):

I tried disconnecting my iPhone from the Internet, the problem disappeared in later launches.

So something is trying to do network stuff and causing the delay.
It's a quick fix, but will do until we find the specific culprit.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue.
What I did was in Xcode go to **Products -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Select the Run tab -> Change the build configuration to Release ( default it was debug mode )** and run the app in the device.

It was much faster and run it as like a native app.

Answer (score 2):

Just experienced this and after an hour of debugging realized I had recently enabled my systems firewall and set it to "Block all incoming connections".

Weird thing is that android was functioning fine on a physical device, however iOS on a physical device was not able to connect to the RN server. Relaxed the firewall rules and now iOS can connect to the RN server.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to sign the app.

Under the Project navigator, click on your app. Then select your target from the project and targets list. Within the "General" tab, find the 'Signing' section. You'll need to specify a team here.

See this link for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW4

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue where I was react-native-splash-screen. After removing it, it is working

Comment: No where does it say we are using this package.

Comment: I agree. But not sure why this work after removing the package. I added this as answer because this resolved my problem.

Comment: In 2020 I am facing this issue. I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 1):

This issue could raise due to the following possibilities:

1. Your run schema set to `release` instead of `debug`, so always expect to load `main.jsbundle`, instead of running from the debug server. Change it by *Product->Schema-> Edit Schema->Run-> Build Configuration: **Debug***

**Check on Xcode log that any message like `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1004` or `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022`.** 
Go to Project->Target->Build Phases-> + -> New Run Script Phase

2. (-1004) You have configured your XCode project from sketch and forgot to enter the react-native xcode script on Build Phases:

For the below version of React Native 50:

`export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh`

For the higher version of React Native 50:

`export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh`

3. (-1022) Your app ATS issue, check on Info.plist, and you can turn off ATS using below code:

   `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>`

Answer (score 1):

For me I am using firebase framework on my project. I forgot the add **GoogleService-Info.plist** file to my xcode project. After add it problem gone away.

Answer (score 1):

For me,
I have followed below steps:

1. **removed node_modules** and **reinstalled node_modules**
2. **restarted metro server**
3. **re-installed the app**

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on my iOS device. I was connected to 4G, not WiFi. I connected to WiFi and it started working immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue when I upload release on **TestFlight**, so what I did is

```
react-native link react-native-splash-screen
```

because some how my splash screen plugin is unlinked. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Best check with all outgoing calls. This might happened if you do call an http request to fetch user for example or during fetching user from storage.

If this call returned error, you'll be stuck in Splash screen.

Additionally, imagine that you have navigation that uses these calls it will be worse.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above do not work for me.

It's really weird in my situation. The router in my company sends both 2.4G and 5.0G wifi. Only connecting to the 2.4G wifi works when debug on real device.

Answer (score -1):

In my case app stack on splash screen on both (debug & release) schemes of build.

Problem was in Capabilities for push Notification and Firebase. Just add this one. [How you can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052185/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-error-when-i)

May be it'll help you:)

Answer (score -1):

Delete node_modules folder
Then run
yarn or npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).