# React Native IOS app not loading from test flight when my mac is shutdown

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native, deployment

I have created a react native app and followed this [Link](https://readybytes.in/blog/how-to-deploy-a-react-native-ios-app-on-the-app-store) to deploy the app in app store, I can install my app through Testflight after redeem my code only when my mac( where I have developed and build the code using xcode) is in its active stage. But when I shutdown my mac and when I tried to install the app from Testflight,it gets waited for some seconds in the splash screen and then it gets crashed. Though I have uploaded the archive build to app store it still get loaded from my mac.

I think I have made something wrong in the settings when I build the app. In schema there is an option like **Debug** and **Release** modes in (Run,Test Profile, Analyse and Archive) Also there is a **debug Executable** checkbox what to do with this?, I don't know whether this has anything related to my issue or did I made anything wrong with the process of deploying my app to app store by referring the above link. Can someone please help to rectify this issue.

This problem doesn't have any code to provide in my question since I hope this is something related to the setting issues while building the Archive. I have been submitting more that 5 build for past few weeks but all get rejected with the same reason. Someone please help If they encounter with the some issue Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346615/react-native-app-stuck-on-splash-screen-on-device-but-works-in-simulator